# Run single specific test from TestNG Suite via gradle command

Tags: java, gradle, testng

I run my TestNG suites via gradle tasks (e.g. `gradle regression`) which are linked to testng xml files like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="SuiteName">
    <test name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="path.to.tests.Test1Runner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test2">
        <classes>
            <class name="path.to.tests.Test2Runner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The gradle task:

```
task regression(type: Test) {

    group = 'verification'
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    //ignoreFailures = true
    useTestNG() {
        scanForTestClasses = true
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
        useDefaultListeners = true
        suites "src/test/resources/suites/regression.xml"
    }
}
```

How can I run only 1 of these tests via gradle command? I want to execute e.g. `gradle regression  -Test1`

Comment: Is `regression` your custom task? Can you post your task ?

Comment: @Pankaj thanks for the hint, I added it to the description

Comment: I'm confused. You've tagged your Question with JUnit, but mention TestNG.

Comment: @Scratte I untagged it now...